# How to downgrade a package in conda?

Tags: python, installation, conda

I tried downgrading parso by

```
conda install parso=0.5.2
```

This seemed to worked and I checked by

```
conda list parso
# packages in environment at /home/thor/.conda/envs/thor:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0    conda-forge
```

However, when I run python, I still get the previous version

```
python
Python 3.8.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr 24 2020, 08:20:52) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import parso
>>> parso.__version__
'0.7.0'
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I downgrade a package so that python finds the downgraded version?
Edit:
I also tried installing in a new environment, with the same result.
In the base environment, conda list parso gives version 0.1.1, but running python again gives version 0.7.0.
So how do I make python run in a specific environment?

Comment: You likely have another Python on your PATH, or PYTHONPATH. Please edit the question to include out put from `python -c 'import parso; print(parso.__spec__)'`, which will reveal where it is loading from.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by using

```
pip uninstall parso
```

Comment: If this worked, that means you weren't working in your virtual-env!

Comment: Then I dont know how to work in my virtual environment. I used source activate <env-name> before starting python.

Comment: I think @merv's commnet was useful, in your previous setup when you had uninstalled `parso` from conda but were still seeing it in your virtual-env, did you find that where that module was coming from?

Comment: @Mansoor yes, I agree. This still sounds like there is another Python that is leaking into the Conda env. If you want to fix the cause and not merely workaround the symptoms, ensure that your PATH and PYTHONPATH do not have other Python's on them.